# How to handle conection with multiple accounts in Meteor?

Tags: facebook, meteor, meteor-accounts

On my app, users can login and signup with the accounts-password package.

I added service configuration and facebook packages to allow them to connect user external service.

For now, users can log in using a "connect with facebook" button,  or using the classical method (email + password).

But my problem is that, when a user log in with facebook, he is only "logged", his profile is empty, all the data i have about him is his _id and profile{name: "his facebook name")}.

I'd like to be able to get more informations to complete his profile from facebook informations, and so, check if it is the first time he connect via facebook. If it is, he must add some informations to be able to naviguate through the website.

The problem is that i can not find ANY usefulll doc about the accounts-facebook package. Even on the official website, there is a link to the atmoshpere package page, but there is nothing else written on this page than the link to the official doc, wich sends me back to atmoshpere ... (Epic Doc....).

I googled a lot about that, but all i find was some smalls tutorials about how to add a "connect with facebook" button and how to set a facebook dev' app ... Nothing new for me.

Could someone guide me plz ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need more data, you need to use the scope parameter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.3#permissions

...but in order to detect returning users, you should ONLY use the id.